# Transfering to function when power of the x in power series is odd

Tags: power-series

Just a little question. When i have even power, it is obvious, for example:
$$\sum _{n=0}^{\infty }\:x^{2n}\:=\:\frac{1}{1-x^2}$$
Is it correct to say that (when the power is odd):
$$\sum _{n=0}^{\infty }\:x^{2n+1}\:=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty \:}\:x^{2n}\cdot x\:=\:\:x\cdot \sum_{n=0}^{\infty \:\:}\:x^{2n}\:=\:\frac{x}{1-x^2} $$

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_progression

Comment: it seems to be correct. you can check it by geometric sequences sit seems to be correct. you can check it by geometric sequences summation:$$a_1+a_1q+a_1q^2+...=\frac{a_1}{1-q}\\|q|<1$$ then put $a_1=x,q=x^2$

Comment: It is exactly correct.(we can use properties of summation).